# memoryleak (node) in IXMLDocument AddChild

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, ixmldomdocument, ixmldomnode

Apparently there is a memory leak in this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  doc: IXMLDocument;
begin
  doc := TXMLDocument.Create(Nil);
  doc.Active := True;
  doc.AddChild('test');
  doc := Nil;
end;
```

Clicking on the button gives me a report of a memory leak.  Is this a false positive or is there a leak?  IDE is Rad Studio 10.2

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51422248/txmldocument-active-false-causes-fastmm4-errormessage-fastmm-detected-that-a#comment89818234_51422248) might be another flavor of your issue, maybe? Do you get the same leak reported when you just let the `IXMLDocument` reference run out of scope instead of using `doc := nil;` to force it?

Comment: Interesting link, thanks!  If I omit the `doc := nil;` I still get the leak.  I tried `doc := nil` when clicking an other button (suggestion from the link you gave), but still the same.  I'm using EurekaLog

Comment: Is it possible that this is a false positive. Can you reproduce this without Eureka using the built in leak detection?

Comment: I added `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;` (hope this was what you meant)  in the FormCreate: it does not report a leak!

Comment: Then I think the issue is with how you are using Eureka.

Comment: No mem leak in 10.3 using FastMM4 in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Eurekalog support: it was a false positive of a RESOURCE leak (not a memory leak as my title says).  Eurekalog did not report a memory leak but a resource leak,sorry for the confusion and thanks for the help (especially the suggestion of a false positive).